# Django setting conditions on join with annotation

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following expression:

```
Product.objects.annotate(views_total=models.Sum('stats__views'))
```

Which correctly joins Product and Stats tables and aggregates stats.views field per product.id:

```
SELECT 
    "product"."id", "product"."name", SUM("stats"."views") AS "views_total" 
FROM 
    "product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stats" ON ("product"."id" = "stats"."product_id") 
GROUP BY "product"."id";
```

**I am trying to figure out how to add a condition on joined Stats table, which would correspond to such query:**

```
SELECT 
    "product"."id", "product"."name", SUM("stats"."views") AS "views_total" 
FROM 
    "product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stats" ON ("product"."id" = "stats"."product_id") AND ("stats"."condition" > 100)
GROUP BY "product"."id";
```

I tried:

```
Product.objects.annotate(views_total=models.Sum('stats__views')).filter(stats__condition__gt = 100)
```

But this results in inner join which doesn't produce the desired result:

```
SELECT 
    "product"."id", "product"."name", SUM("stats"."views") AS "views_total" 
FROM 
    "product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stats" ON ("product"."id" = "stats"."product_id") 
INNER JOIN 
    "stats" T3 ON ("product"."id" = T3."product_id") 
WHERE (T3."condition" > 100) 
GROUP BY "product"."id";
```

Comment: Have you solved this? I kinda did, but it's so ugly, I thought there must be a better solution.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch I "solved" it by extracting the raw sql from a queryset, doing an sql injection, and running it. I bet yours isn't this ugly, so I would love to see it :) I spent a lot of time searching for a solution, it appears that conditional joins are just beyond django orm capabilities, there is no solution to this.

Comment: I'll post my answer later today, but just as a curiosity. I'll probably remove it from my code and go with a raw sql :P.

Comment: After all I gave up and went with the raw queries (which resulted in creating a custom pagination class and raw queries for this pagination class, and putting custom LIMIT OFFSET clauses into raw query being run by paginator based on the original query and so on...). My previous solution didn't work and broke some other things. So for whoever comes here: DON'T WASTE YOUR TIME TRYING TO GET DJANGO TO DO CONDITIONAL JOINS, IT WON'T WORK! :)